# Deep-learning library Neon DataIterator / ArrayIterator init error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

When trying to set up the DataIterator as explained on [neon tutorial](http://neon.nervanasys.com/docs/latest/datasets.html#add-a-new-dataset).

```
from neon.data import DataIterator
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(10000, 3072)
y = np.random.randint(1, 11, 10000)

train = DataIterator(X=X, y=y, nclass=10, lshape=(3, 32, 32))
```

I encountered a weird error:

```
ERROR:neon.data.dataiterator:DataIterator class has been deprecated and  renamed"ArrayIterator" please use that name.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "neon/data/dataiterator.py", line 168, in __init__
    super(DataIterator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "neon/data/dataiterator.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.Xdev = [self.be.array(x) for x in X]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

I then tried with ArrayIterator, keeping X, y the same.

```
ArrayIterator(X=X, y=y, nclass=10, lshape=(3,32,32))
```

With the same NoneType error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "neon/data/dataiterator.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.Xdev = [self.be.array(x) for x in X]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Why would this be the case? Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by generating [backend](http://neon.nervanasys.com/docs/latest/backends.html).

```
from neon.backends import gen_backend

be = gen_backend()
(...)
```

Comment: what did you do with "be"? if you call gen_backend() is neon then setting a global and are you passing `be` to something of `ArrayIterator`?

Comment: Neon sets a global variable to "be". Neon uses this to perform every calculation and allocation of memory. Hardware abstraction layer which makes it easy to switch between e.g. cpu and gpu backends.